# Echarts Warnings: Expected color but found ‘undefined’

Tags: echarts

I use Echarts and found that it generates massive amounts of the following warnings in firefox

- Expected color but found ‘undefined’.........from DOM
- Expected color but found ‘null’...................from DOM

It does this when I move my mouse over the bar graphs that I use. Especially when I have tooltip:{}
enabled and defined. The same messages are also generated in the example page of Echarts.
Should I be concerned about these warnings and can I do something about it.

Thanks Oscar Goos

Comment: By the way, to be more specific it generates these messages when I move my mouse over the colored bars and legenda area of the graph.